# Why can't I delete this directory?

Tags: linux, permissions

Transcript:

```
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Jun 14 05:13 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Jun 14 04:57 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 12 00:29 DARN
$ ls -al DARN/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 12 00:29 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Jun 14 05:13 ..
$ sudo lsof | grep DARN
$ sudo rmdir DARN
rmdir: failed to remove 'DARN': Operation not permitted
```

I can rename the directory, I can even move it outside of its parent. Reboot didn't help either.

This is Arch Linux 4.0.5-1-ARCH (current).

Update: Dan suggested extended attributes:

```
$ sudo lsattr .
---------------- ./DARN
$ sudo lsattr DARN/
$
```

I guess that means there aren't any?

Comment: Use chattr/lsattr to check for things like immutable flag

Comment: Two questions: on which filesystem is DARN located  (ext4, fat32,...), and can you post the output of ls -id * issued in DARN's parent directory.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: 1) btrfs. 2) `256 DARN`

Comment: Pls read my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [BTRFS FAQ](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Problem_FAQ#I_cannot_delete_an_empty_directory):

> if you get:
>
> ```
> rmdir: failed to remove ‘emptydir’: Operation not permitted
> ```
>
> then this is probably because "emptydir" is actually a subvolume.
>   You can check whether this is the case with:
>
> ```
>  # btrfs subvolume list -a /mountpoint
> ```
>
> To delete the subvolume you'll have to run:
>
> ```
>  # btrfs subvolume delete emptydir
> ```

This is apparently a well-known problem, with a well-defined solution. If this works, I would also run

```
  btrfs check --repair /dev/sdXY
```

just in case.

If all else fails, run

```
     lsof +D /path/to/DARN
```

from *outside* DARN, and see whether anything is actually accessing the directory so fast that you cannot see it.

Comment: You got it! Must be that `systemd-nspawn` turned this into a subvolume when I was playing around with it.